# An alternative way to count a string appears in an array

Tags: javascript

I am counting how many times strings contain an `aa` appears in an array. I dont think there is something wrong with my code. like below

```js
const regex_aa = /aa[^(aa)]?$/s;
let arr = [];
const sstr = ['aa', 'aaaa', 'cc', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'bbaa'];
sstr.filter(e => {
if (regex_aa.test(e)) {
  arr.push(e);
}
});

console.log(arr.length);
```

So the number is `3` which is correct. 
However, the next job is to count how many times appears, then it looks like

```js
   const regex_aa = /aa[^(aa)]?$/s;
    const regex_bb = /bb[^(aa)]?$/s;
    let arr1 = [];
    let arr2 = [];

    const sstr = ['aa', 'aaaa', 'cc', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'bbaa'];
    sstr.filter(e => {
      if (regex_aa.test(e)) {
        arr1.push(e);
      }
      if (regex_bb.test(e)) {
        arr2.push(e);
      }
    });

    console.log(arr1.length, arr2.length);
```

so each time if I want to find the number of a new string, I have to create a new `let`, I found this way is a bit clumsy. Is there a better solution for counting strings? Thanks

Comment: If you use `filter()` you shouldn't push into an array, you should just return the comparison result. `filter()` will return the new array.

Comment: `regex_js` should be `regex_aa`. But your regex doesn't make much sense. If you just want to know if the string contains `aa`, it should just he `/aa/`

Comment: `bb` occurs twice in the `sstr`, so shouldn't its result be `2`, not `1`?

Comment: `[^(aa)]?` doesn't mean whatever you think it does.

Comment: `bb[^(aa)` copied in a wrong way, but `bb[^(aa)` here is for `bbaa`, thanks! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You clearly don't understand what `[]` means in a regular expression. It's not for grouping.

Comment: `[^(aa)]` means to match a single character that isn't `(`, `a` or `)`. It makes no sense to repeat a character inside `[]`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar the original code was long and messy, I was in rush, copied and pasted without checking it. That why `[^(aa)]`. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you're actually using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression here is overkill - instead, count up with `.reduce` by testing whether the string being iterated over `.includes` the substring you're looking for:

```js
const countOccurrences = (arr, needle) => (
  arr.reduce((a, haystack) => a + haystack.includes(needle), 0)
);
console.log(countOccurrences(['aa', 'aaaa', 'cc', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'bbaa'], 'aa'));
console.log(countOccurrences(['aa', 'aaaa', 'cc', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'bbaa'], 'bb'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and make is as a function.

Also, there is not need to use `regex` in-order to find a substring inside a string, you can use [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for that

Something like this:

```js
const sstr = ['aa', 'aaaa', 'cc', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'bbaa'];

function countAppearanceOf(needle, arr) {
  return arr.reduce((count, item) => count + (item.indexOf(needle) > -1 ? 1 : 0), 0);
}

console.log(countAppearanceOf('aa', sstr));
```

Or even more generelized method, you can create a `predicate` method.

```js
const sstr = ['aa', 'aaaa', 'cc', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'bbaa'];

function generalCountAppearanceOf(needle, arr, predicate) {
  return arr.reduce((count, item) => count + (predicate(needle, item) ? 1 : 0), 0);
}

function generateCounterByPredicate(predicate) {
  return (needle, arr) => generalCountAppearanceOf(needle, arr, predicate);
}

function predicatWithIndexOf(needle, item) {
  return item.indexOf(needle) > -1;
}

function predicatWithRegex(needle, item) {
  return /bb(aa)+/.test(item);
}

const countAppearanceOfWithIndexOf = generateCounterByPredicate(predicatWithIndexOf);
const countAppearanceOfWithRegex = generateCounterByPredicate(predicatWithRegex);

console.log(countAppearanceOfWithIndexOf('aa', sstr));

console.log(countAppearanceOfWithRegex('aa', sstr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just count up object properties

```
let word_count = { 
    aa: 0,
    bb: 0
 }
```

...

```
  if (regex_aa.test(e)) {
    word_count.aa += 1
  }
  if (regex_bb.test(e)) {
    word_count.bb += 1
  }
```

console.log(word_count)
console.log(word_count.aa)

Answer (score 0):

```
const v = 'aa';
new RegExp(v + '[^(' + v + ')]?$', 's')
```

Comment: You're making the same mistake he did with the `[^(aa)]` regexp, which makes no sense.

Comment: I've just wanted to give an option to user dynamic regexp, it doesnt matter what it is